# How to store the result of a print function () into a variable to include it in a f string

Tags: python, string, f-string

I have the following dataframe:

```
data={'Process_ID':['12345-98', '23547-75', '85763-99','44231-56','78456-00','53218-87'],
     'Date': ['2021-06-30','2022-08-10','2021-06-15','2023-10-02','2024-04-03','2021-06-25'],
     'Check': ['True','False','False','True','True','False']}

df=pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

The output is the following:

```
 Process_ID        Date  Check
0   12345-98  2021-06-30   True
1   23547-75  2022-08-10  False
2   85763-99  2021-06-15  False
3   44231-56  2023-10-02   True
4   78456-00  2024-04-03   True
5   53218-87  2021-06-25  False
```

I wanted to select the process ids and the due dates only for the rows where check="True", so I did this:

```
def printfunc():
    df['Check']=pd.eval(df['Check'].astype(str).str.title())
    out=df.loc[df['Check'],['Process_ID','Date']].T
    for x in out:
        print('Process ID:',out[x].values[0],'\nDue Date:',out[x].values[1],'\n')

content=printfunc()

content
```

Output:

```
Process ID: 12345-98 
Due Date: 2021-06-30 

Process ID: 44231-56 
Due Date: 2023-10-02 

Process ID: 78456-00 
Due Date: 2024-04-03
```

Now, I want to include the 'content variable' inside an f-string, because I will automate an email to display this information. However, when I try to do it, it returns a 'None' value:

```
email_text=f"""

Dear,

The due dates for the processes are the following:

{content}

Thank you.

Best Regards,

"""

print(email_text)
```

Output:

```
Dear,

The due dates for the processes are the following:

None

Thank you.

Best Regards,
```

How can I include this variable inside an f-string to be able to print it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
def printfunc():
    s=''
    df['Check']=pd.eval(df['Check'].astype(str).str.title())
    out=df.loc[df['Check'],['Process_ID','Date']].T
    for x in out:
        s+='Process ID:'+out[x].values[0]+'\nDue Date: '+out[x].values[1]+'\n\n'
    return s

content=printfunc()
```

Finally:

```
email_text=f"""

Dear,

The due dates for the processes are the following:

{content}

Thank you.

Best Regards,

"""

print(email_text)
```

**Explainations:**

this function is just printing the values it's not returning anything so that's the reason that you are getting `'None'`

so we created a variable `s` and assign empty character `''` to it and then adding and assigning the string back to it inside the for loop in the function

**P.S:** sorry for bad explaination...I am not good in explaining things **:(**

Answer (score -3):

`print(df)` is just writing to standard output whatever `str(df)` returns.